# Query about Installing Ubuntu Desktop in VirtualBox

Tags: software-installation

I am looking to install the desktop version of Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

During the installation setup I am informed that the installation will wipe out any current operating systems, applications, and files.

Is this related only to the virtual-disk area I have configured or is this in general for everything on my host disk-drive.

I know this is a rather dumb-question but the installation information here appears rather ambiguous making me wonder what it is actually going to do.

Comment: It's only about the virtual disk, don't worry.

Answer (score -1):

When you are doing installation inside virtualbox, as the setup is running inside virtualbox, it will be affecting the virtual disk which you created and not the host OS, so no need to worry. :)

Comment: Thank you for your update...